# Ember promise isPending not firing if thenable

Tags: ember.js, promise

I want to show a loading spinner in an ember component when I load some data from the store. If there is an error from the store, I want to handle it appropriately.

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
cachedCampaignDataIsPending: computed.readOnly('fetchCachedCampaignData.isPending'),

fetchCachedCampaignData: computed('campaign', function() {
  return this.get('store').findRecord('cachedCampaignMetric').then( (cachedMetrics) => {
    this.set('cachedCampaignData', cachedMetrics);
  }, () => {
    this.set('errors', true);
  });
}),
```

This will properly set the errors to true if the server responds with an error, however, the `cachedCampaignDataIsPending` is not acting properly. It does not get set to true.

However, if I rewrite my code to make the computed property not be *thenable*, then it does fire propertly.

```
fetchCachedCampaignData: computed('campaign', function() {
  return this.get('store').findRecord('cachedCampaignMetric');
}),
```

Anyone know the reason why, or how to make it fire properly, using the then/catch logic?

Thanks.

**Update**

I found that this works for me and gives me what I need.

```
cachedCampaignDataIsPending: computed.readOnly('fetchCachedCampaignData.isPending'),

fetchCachedCampaignData: computed('campaign', function() {
  let promise = this.get('store').findRecord('cachedCampaignMetric');
  promise.then( (cachedMetrics) => {
    this.set('cachedCampaignData', cachedMetrics);
  }, () => {
    this.set('errors', true);
  });
  return promise;
}),
```

Comment: You should post this as answer and accept it.